# Jenkins display custom parameter value name

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am using extended choice parameter to display choice parameters using jenkins groovy script and I want to set the choice parameter to select all the choice parameter values by default.
Below is the groovy script.

```
    if(LIST.equals('abc')){
         return ["Select:selected", "abc_test1", "abc_test2", "abc_test3"]
         }
         else if(LIST.equals('xyz')){
         return ["xyz xyz xyz":"ALL_XYZ:selected", "xyz_test1", "xyz_test2", "xyz_test3"]
         }
```

I get the below error -

```
startup failed:
Script1: 5: Unexpected node type: EXPR found when expecting type: LABELED_ARG at line: 5 column: 48. File: Script1 @ line 5, column 48.
    xyz xyz":"ALL_XYZ:selected", "xyz_test1
```

Because I am combining MAP with LIST in groovy which is not allowed I guess.

But when I use the below code which puts the MAP values in the square brackets, the parameter name is displayed as shown in the screenshot.

```
if(LIST.equals('abc')){
     return ["Select:selected", "abc_test1", "abc_test2", "abc_test3"]
     }
     else if(LIST.equals('xyz')){
     return [**["xyz xyz xyz":"ALL_XYZ:selected"]**, "xyz_test1", "xyz_test2", "xyz_test3"]
     }
```

[image]

Can I get some help??

Comment: Actually your question is how to display "ALL_XYZ:selected" instead of [object Object] in your choice parameters?

Comment: Yes Catalin. I want to display "ALL_XYZ:selected" and also the other choice parameters too.